# IllegalStateException: Fragment DetailFragment did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragment-manager

I got a weird error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DetailFragment{478548c} (790a9d4b-aae5-425a-a41d-2ab5785e5479) id=0x7f0b1c79 DetailFragment} did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireView(SourceFile:1781)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.captureOutSharedElements(SourceFile:846)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureSharedElementsOrdered(SourceFile:758)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(SourceFile:378)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(SourceFile:155)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2001)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:1959)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1861)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(SourceFile:413)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

The error occurred till now only 3 times on different devices. It's really seldom compared to usage of the app. And I cannot reproduce it. According to our tracking it occured when the user pressed back on this Fragment. This fragment doesn't override the `onBackPressed()` but the parent overrides it and there is nothing what can help me to recognise the problem:

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    return false;
}
```

so I have no idea where to search the bug.

EDIT: this fragment also doesn't override `onCreateView()`, it does the parent:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dataBinding = inflateBinding(inflater, container);
    initViews();

    if (firstStart) {
        onFirstCreateView();
    } else {
        onReCreateView(savedInstanceState);
    }
    firstStart = false;

    return dataBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: Can you post onCreateView() ?

Comment: @ Prince Ali here you are

Comment: Have you resolved a problem?

Comment: @CoolMind still not

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin, thanks. I also got this exception on 3 devices.